# ¿Cómo podría ordenar este formulario por orden alfabetico?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente dilema, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver.

Tengo un formulario en HTML que dice lo siguiente :

```
<div class="form-group">
                 <select name="estado" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Cualquier estado</option>
                    <option value="">------</option>
                    {loop="$fsc->estados->all()"}
                       {if="$value->id==$fsc->estado"}
                       <option value="{$value->id}" selected="">{$value->descripcion}</option>
                       {else}
                       <option value="{$value->id}">{$value->descripcion}</option>
                       {/if}
                    {/loop}
                 </select>
              </div>
```

Esta petición me devuelve unos valores por nº de ID. Lo que quiero conseguir es que ordene por orden alfabético. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra colaboración.

Saludos.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Esta sintaxis, {loop=...}{/loop} entiendo que no es de HTML, sino de algún tipo de algún lenguaje de templating que no identifico ahora mismo. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir una etiqueta con el lenguaje que estés utilizando para crear esos bucles? Así hay más probabilidades que alguien que entienda de esas tecnoloǵias te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar tu lista normal, y cuando acabe de cargar la pagina llamar a la funcion `organizar()`, la cual toma cada opcion y la colca un un array , y luego con la funcion  `.sort()`    se organizaria, y despues poner este nuevo array en el select.

```js
function organizar() {
  var lb = document.getElementById('mylist');
  arrTexts = new Array();

  for (i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) {
    arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text;
  }
  arrTexts.sort();

  for (i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) {
    lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
    lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
  }
}
```

```html
Original
<select>
  <option value="">AC</option>
  <option value="">AB</option>
  <option value="">BD</option>
  <option value="">BA</option>
  <option value="">BC</option>
</select>

Organizada al oprimir el  boton
<select id=mylist>
  <option value="">AC</option>
  <option value="">AB</option>
  <option value="">BD</option>
  <option value="">BA</option>
  <option value="">BC</option>
</select>

<button onclick="organizar()">Organizar</button>
```

Comment: Esta muy bien la respuesta pero colocar una nueva funcion no me sirver porque es bastante dinamico yla verdad que resultaria bastante engorroso , me gustaria que que se mostrara automaticamente organizada. Gracias. Saludos.